# Django: How to correct created date/time

Tags: python, django

I've a model Order, that has a field created. It's intention is to show when the order took place (date and time speaking).

I'm using this line to create the field in the model:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, the reviewing it from admin panel, it shows It was created in the future: 10:52 pm of 27/12. When the time right now is: 6:11 pm. You can see these details in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I make sure the correct time gets recorded in productio env? It'll be hosted using Google Cloud Products.

Right know I'm in development env.

**View that creates the Order**:

```
@csrf_exempt
def cart_charge(request):

    culqipy.public_key = settings.CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    culqipy.secret_key = settings.CULQI_SECRET_KEY


    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
    currency_code = request.POST.get('currency_code')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    source_id = request.POST.get('source_id')
    last_four = request.POST.get('last_four')


    dir_charge = {"amount": int(amount), "currency_code": currency_code,
                  "email": email,
                  "source_id": source_id}

    print(dir_charge)

    charge = culqipy.Charge.create(dir_charge)

transaction_amount = int(charge['amount'])/100 #Necesario dividir entre 100 para obtener el monto real,
                                                   #Esto debido a cómo Culqi recibe los datos de los pagos


    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    shipping_address1 = request.user.profile.shipping_address1

    shipping_address2 = request.user.profile.shipping_address2

    shipping_department = request.user.profile.shipping_department

    shipping_province = request.user.profile.shipping_province

    shipping_district = request.user.profile.shipping_district

    order = Order.objects.create(
        token = charge['id'],
        total =transaction_amount,
        email= email, #Using email entered in Culqi module, NOT user.email. Could be diff.
        last_four = last_four,
        created = current_time,
        shipping_address1 = shipping_address1,
        shipping_address2 = shipping_address2,
        shipping_department = shipping_department,
        shipping_province = shipping_province,
        shipping_district = shipping_district

    )

    order.save()

    return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

**Oder model**:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank = True, verbose_name= 'Correo electrónico')
    last_four = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, default='')


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Order'
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return "Order by: " + str(self.id) + " for " + str(self.total)
```

Comment: I imagine this is a timezone conversion issue.  What timezone do you have in `settings.py`?  Recent versions of Django default to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide current date when creating model object, because you already set option 'auto_now_add=True', which will set date automatically when you create a model object, for example:

```
order = Order.objects.create(
    token = charge['id'],
    total =transaction_amount,
    email= email, #Using email entered in Culqi module, NOT user.email. Could be diff.
    last_four = last_four,
    shipping_address1 = shipping_address1,
    shipping_address2 = shipping_address2,
    shipping_department = shipping_department,
    shipping_province = shipping_province,
    shipping_district = shipping_district
)
order.save()
print(order.created) # return current time on in server's timezone
```